# unitofwork and repositorypattern An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I have a complex object which has references to other objects, I am trying to save it from my web application.

so, in my webapplication, I call the business logic, and from the bl, I call the DAL Facade, and then the DAL.

When I execute the Insert method I am having the exception.

**Code in the DAL layer, this is where the exception is raised.**

```
public void InsertEcoBonusRequest(EcoBonusRequest ecoBonusRequest)
        {
            _context.EcoBonusRequests.Add(ecoBonusRequest);
        }
```

**Code in the Unitofwork.cs**

```
public void Save()
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

 private RequestBaseRepository _requestBaseRepository;

 public EcoBonusRequestRepository EcoBonusRequestRepository
            {
                get
                {
                    return _ecobonusworkflowRepository ??
                            (_ecobonusworkflowRepository = new EcoBonusRequestRepository(_context));
                }
            }
```

**Code in the dal facade:**

```
private  static readonly UnitOfWork UnitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

        public void Save(EcoBonusRequest ecoBonusRequest)
        {
            UnitOfWork.EcoBonusRequestRepository.InsertEcoBonusRequest(ecoBonusRequest);
        }
```

**Code in the BL**

```
public void Save(EcoBonusRequest ecoBonusRequest)
        {
            EcoBonusRequestFacade.Save(ecoBonusRequest);

}


**Code in the page.aspx.cs, as you can see the element ecobonusworkflow is neverstored in the database, but the navigation entities are stored already.**

 var dealer = DealerBL.GetDealer(Nuteres);
  var requester = RequesterBL.GetRequester(int.Parse(DdlRequester.SelectedItem.Value));
                var selectedVehicle = VehicleBL.GetVehicle(VehicleInformationControl.Chassis);


var ecoBonusWorkflow = new EcoBonusRequest
                {
                    IsOnHold = true,
                    AmmountWithoutVAT = decimal.Parse(TxtVatExcluded.Text),
                    AmmountWithVAT = decimal.Parse(TxtVatIncluded.Text),
                    BrandReturnedVehicle = TxtBrandReturnedVehicle.Text,
                    ChassisReturnedVehicle = TxtChasisReturnedVehicle.Text,
                    Percentage = (decimal.Parse(TxtVatExcluded.Text)/VehicleInformationControl.InvoicedAmmount)*100,
                    Comments = TxtComments.Text,
                    Customer = new Customer
                    {
                        FirstName = TxtFirstName.Text,
                        LastName = TxtLastName.Text,
                        Address = new Address
                        {
                            Street = TxtStreet.Text,
                            Number = TxtNumber.Text,
                            Box = TxtBox.Text,
                            City = TxtCity.Text,
                            Zip = TxtZip.Text
                        }
                    },
                    CurrentStatus = "Approval1",
                    Dealer = dealer,
                    Requester = requester,
                    VehicleDesctructionDate = DateTime.Parse(TxtVehicleDestructionDateReturnedVehicle.Text, userCulture),
                    DestructionCertificateNumberReturnedVehicle = TxtDestructionCertificateNumberReturnedVehicle.Text,
                    TypeReturnedVehicle = TxtTypeReturnedVehicle.Text,
                    Vehicle = selectedVehicle
                };
                EcoBonusRequest = ecoBonusWorkflow;
                UploadFiles();
                RedirectToPage("~/Requests/confirmation.aspx");
```

Comment: Where did you get the `ecoBonusRequest` to save?  Is it loaded from database ?

Comment: maybe I need to add first the address entity, then the customer object, and then the ecobonus request object, or EF handles this automaticallY?

Comment: the error is thrown exaclty on this line: on DAL   public void InsertEcoBonusRequest(EcoBonusRequest ecoBonusRequest)
            {
                _context.EcoBonusRequests.Add(ecoBonusRequest);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception states that your entity, or navigation entities of the root entity is already attached to another context. 
Depending on your architecture, you should either create a new context and attach it every time; or if you are reusing the context you should refresh the context with new values.

In your case, it seems you are creating a new context, but a previous context has not been disposed thus the entity is still attached to the older context. In this case, just reuse the older context instead of creating a new one.

Comment: In my scenario an object is created in a page, in memory, attached to nothing, then its saved to session, then in the 2nd page which is called Confirmation, it takes the object from session, shows all the info the user typed on the first page, and when the user submits, then it will add the object to the database, in the first page I never used the context.  Can you tell me the solution by code?

Comment: reading again, the entity I created is not in the database, but the navigation entities ARE stored in the database, so that might be the problem, I still have no idea how to solve this by code.

Comment: Where are you attaching navigation properties to the root object?

Comment: in the page.aspx.cs, please see the update, the dealer and requester are navigation properties that already exist on the database, the ecobonusrequest its in memory at that time.

Comment: are using the same DealerBL instance to save the entity or are you using another BL?

Comment: the dealer its saved using another BL class, the same for the Requester, it uses another BL Class.

Comment: the error is thrown exaclty on this line: on DAL   public void InsertEcoBonusRequest(EcoBonusRequest ecoBonusRequest)
            {
                _context.EcoBonusRequests.Add(ecoBonusRequest);

Comment: you can't use another BL class because it creates another context for same object. Can u use the same BL class.

Comment: Each of your BL classes has their own unitofwork. Thus each one is creating a new context. If you want to use just one context, just remove the static IUnitOfWork declaration to one place. please try whether this solves your problem... Also this violates the idea behind IUnitOfWork. You can not make changes in a transactional way while having multiple contexts for each business layer.

Comment: there is a reference implementation of microsoft spain. http://microsoftnlayerapp.codeplex.com/